# Read text file display

Tags: c#, string, console, char, ascii

Good morning, I wanted to know how I can do a kindly thing. I have a .txt file where a design is represented in ASCII. Via console I want to read this file and add any ASCII character in an array of type char. How can I do that knowing to read the file I have to use a string? I found this way but I do not know how to use the char

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"best.txt");
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please post your .txt file here?

Comment: This is an example of what I have in the .txt file

Comment: I have read your question three times and I can no figure out what exactly you're asking.

Comment: what char you want to add in the array and where to add?

Comment: I have an array of type char, I would add every single character in the .txt file

Comment: please past your .txt file content here so I can help you.

Answer (score 1):

hmmm, your question isn't clear enough.. But.. Do I have this right?
Do you want to map all characters in your text file to an 2d array?
Something like this:

```
[0, 0] = "a"
[0, 1] = "b"
[0, 2] = "c"
..<omited>..
[4, 0] = "x"
...
and so on...
```

**A little test text file:**

```
abcdefghij
1234567890
jihgfedcba
0987654321
xxxxxxxxxx
0000000000
yyyyyyyyyy
9999999999
----------
!!!!!!!!!!
```

**C# Code:**

```
static void Main()
{
    String input = File.ReadAllText(@"test.txt");   // read file content
    input = input.Replace("\r\n", "\n");            // get rid of \r

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    string[,] result = new string[10,10];           // hardcoded for testing purposes
    foreach (var row in input.Split('\n'))          // loop through each row
    {
        j = 0;
        foreach (var col in row.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray()) // split to array
        {                                                            // and loop through each char

            result[i, j] = col;                                      // Add the char to the jagged array => result
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}


// EDIT: added some code to print out the result.
// Print all elements in the 2d array.
int rowLength = result.GetLength(0);
int colLength = result.GetLength(1);

for (int k = 0; k < rowLength; k++)
{
    for (int h = 0; h < colLength; h++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", result[k, h]);
    }
    Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

*I've hardcoded the size of the array in this example.*